# How to multiple upload images in Django (and dispaly them as carousels)?

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms

I would like add multiple upload images for single product page carousels (so, I need four [] (or {}?..) of images). I need multiple upload because number of photos in different product cards may be different: from 2 to 6.
Now I can select multiple files to upload in the admin panel but can't save it. I have an error:

```
TypeError at /admin/product/product/8/change/

Field 'id' expected a number but got <TemporaryUploadedFile: CON_1_mob.jpg (image/jpeg)>.

Request Method:     POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/product/product/8/change/
Django Version:     5.0
Exception Type:     TypeError

Exception Location:     /home/a/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py, line 2114, in get_prep_value
Raised during:  django.contrib.admin.options.change_view
```

My code:

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from multiupload.fields import MultiFileField

class Product(models.Model):
    carousel_items = models.ManyToManyField('ProductImage', related_name='carousel_items', blank=True)
    carousel_items_mob = models.ManyToManyField('ProductImage', related_name='carousel_items_mob', blank=True)
    interior_items = models.ManyToManyField('ProductImage', related_name='interior_items', blank=True)
    interior_items_mob = models.ManyToManyField('ProductImage', related_name='interior_items_mob', blank=True)
    # many another fields

    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.product_full_name

class ProductImage(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='product_items/%Y/%m/%d')
```

forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from .models import Product, ProductImage 
from multiupload.fields import MultiFileField

class CustomProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
    carousel_items = MultiFileField(min_num=1, max_num=10, required=False)
    carousel_items_mob = MultiFileField(min_num=1, max_num=10, required=False)
    interior_items = MultiFileField(min_num=1, max_num=10, required=False)
    interior_items_mob = MultiFileField(min_num=1, max_num=10, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = '__all__'

    def save(self, commit=True):
        product = super().save(commit=False)
        
        if commit:
            product.save()

        for file in self.cleaned_data['carousel_items']:
            image = ProductImage(product=product, image=file)
            image.save()
        for file in self.cleaned_data['carousel_items_mob']:
            image = ProductImage(product=product, image=file)
            image.save()
        for file in self.cleaned_data['interior_items']:
            image = ProductImage(product=product, image=file)
            image.save()
        for file in self.cleaned_data['interior_items_mob']:
            image = ProductImage(product=product, image=file)
            image.save()

        return product
```

views.py:

```
def single_product(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        product_form = ProductForm(request.POST)
        image_form = ProductImageForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if product_form.is_valid() and image_form.is_valid():
            product = product_form.save()
            for image in request.FILES.getlist('images'):
                product_image = ProductImage.objects.create(image=image)
                product_image.product = product
                product_image.save()
            return redirect('single_product', product_slug=product.product_slug)
    else:
        product_form = ProductForm()
        image_form = ProductImageForm()
    return render(request, 'single_product.html', {'product_form': product_form, 'image_form': image_form})
```

admin.py:

```
class ProductImagelInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = ProductImage
    extra = 1
    
@admin.register(Product)
class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('product_full_name', 'fabric_name', 'price', 'price_sale', 'show_on_category_page', 'popular', 'is_new', 'available_in_showroom', 'available_for_delivery_2', 'created', 'updated')
    form = CustomProductForm
    inlines = [ProductImagelInline]
```

What I'll change? Where is my mistake?..

Comment: What is the `id` field of your `Product` model?

Comment: Just so: 
id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)